# Large NOT IN Statement vs Creating/Populating Temp Table

Tags: mysql, temporary-tables

I have a large daily data feed which can contain up to around 5,000 ID's. I need to delete all pre-existing records in the DB that are not referenced in the new feed. Should I create a temporary table for these 5,000 ID's, and run a LEFT JOIN IF NULL DELETE statement? Or, is it all the same if I just pass the ID's over and run a DELETE IF NOT IN statement. My assumption is that MySQL would do the work of creating the temp table for me when using IN statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a large set you may want to use an `NOT EXISTS` clause rather than a `NOT IN` clause.  It will help if you index the id on your feed table.  Using an index will allow the optimizer to use the index rather than reading the table.  Try a query like:

```
DELETE
FROM    table
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT  feed.id
    FROM    feed
    WHERE   feed.id = table.id )
```

Comment: Thank you BillThor, your answer was the tipping point in my decision to rebuild my entire process. When building a large import feed like mine, I believe a staging table is the only way to go, particularly if you want to run batch queries. Otherwise, you'll require mountains of application code to accomplish what you can with just a little SQL